# Set Evenet Listener on Selectobox is disabled(DOMAttrModified)

Tags: javascript, events, drop-down-menu, listener

I would like to set an event listener on a selectbox which should be triggerd while the attribute was changed to disabled. I tryed the following:

```
<select id="a">
    <option>Heino</option>
    <option>Michael Jackson</option>
    <option>Tom Waits</option>
    <option>Nina Hagen</option>
    <option>Marianne Rosenberg</option>
</select>
<button id="b">Action</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function() {
    alert(0);
}, false);

var b = document.getElementById("b");
b.onclick = function() {
    a.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
};
</script>
```

By changing the disabled attribute to another attribute for example a everything is working fine. Do you have any idea to trigger this event? A solution for all browsers would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Mutation events are deprecated. Use mutation observers instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `a.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')` you disable `<select>` and not a specific `<option>`. If you want to **disable** the **selected option** if you click the button:

```
var b = document.getElementById("b");
b.onclick = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
        if (a[i].selected == true) {
            a[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
};
```